# Bootstrap 4 carousel indicators active:first issue workaround

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and use  custom arrows for left and right.

Bootstrap is not checking for `li` elements to add the `active` class and just adds class to the first element it finds.

This issue indicates incorrect state of the active slide.

e.g.

[image]

instead of

[image]

Reproduce: https://csandreas1.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2022-02-04.html

```
<div class="carousel-indicators">
    <img class="carousel-arrows carousel-arrow-left" src="/img/icons/arrow-circle-left.svg" onclick="carouselID.carousel('prev')" alt="previous" />
    <li data-target="#carousel"  data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel"  data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel"  data-slide-to="2></li>
    <img class="carousel-arrows" src="/img/icons/arrow-circle-right.svg" onclick="carouselID.carousel('next')" alt="next" />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should move the arrows out of `carouselExampleIndicators` div as per the example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/carousel/#with-indicators

Comment: This does not solve the issue I have

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by wrapping the carousel-indicators inside another div.

```
<div class="wrapper-div">
 .. icon arrow left
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
  </div>
 .. icon arrow right
</div>
```